# Program opens all applications

Tags: java, user-interface, desktop-application, executable

In my program, I have stored an `ArrayList` of all of my desktop icons locations. My problem is that when I click on one icon, my computer tries to open every last program, folder and file all at one time, when I really just want to open whatever was clicked on. How can I have this open this open without the bug of launching every other program?

```
public void executeUserProgram(Point cursorPosition)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < icons_.getIcon().size(); i++)
    {
        if (icons_.getIconDimension().get(i).contains(cursorPosition)) 
        {
            try 
            {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(
                        new File(icons_.getFilePath().get(i)));
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop still continues after it's found the icon. Add a `return` or `break` statement inside the `if` or `try`.

```
try{
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(icons_.getFilePath().get(i)));
    break;
}
```